# awkでグループ化して最大値を出したい

Tags: linux, bash, awk

このようなファイルがあります。
-- test.txt --
AAA.001
AAA.002
AAA.003
BBB.001
BBB.002

から、
AAA.003
BBB.002
というように、AAAに続く最大値、BBBに続く最大値を取得できないでしょうか。

現在は、

cat test.txt | awk '$0 ~ "AAA" {print $0}' | awk '{field = $NF} END {print field}'

のように一つずつやっています。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: awk を使わなくても、例えば、`sort -t. -k1,1 -k2,2nr test.txt | uniq -w4` としても良いかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。こちらの方法でも上手くいきました。uniqの使い方がとても参考になりました！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWK 使うと `001` とかが数値の 1 に勝手に変換されて面倒なのであまりおすすめしませんが、`.` 以降が 3 桁決め打ちで

```
awk -F '\\.' '
{
  key = $1;
  old = -1;
  if (key in alist) {
    old = alist[key];
  };
  new = $2;
  if (new > old) {
    alist[key]= new
  }
}
END{
  for (key in alist){
    printf "%s.%03d\n", key, alist[key];
  }
}' test.txt
```

と FS を `.` にし、`alist` という配列にキーを `AAA` の部分、値を `001` の数値表現に格納していき、最後に表示してます。

数値部分が3桁とは限らないのであれば、`alist` への出し入れで数値←→元の文字列への変換をするとか、何らかの工夫が必要になってくるので、既にコメントに出てるような AWK 使わない解の方が簡単だと思います。

Comment: 数値部分の桁数まで考えていただいてありがとうございます。希望通りに動作しました！

Answer (score 1):

参考までに、入力データ(`test.txt`)において `AAA.*` や `BBB.*` のデータが連続しているのであれば、awk で以下の様にも書く事ができます。

```awk
awk -F. '
  k!=$1{if(NR>1){print k FS v};k=$1;v=$2;next}
  $2>v{v=$2}
  END{print k FS v}
' test.txt
```

プレフィックス(`$1`:`AAA` や `BBB` の部分)が変化した場合にリセット、同じ場合は `.` 以降の数値(`$2`)を比較して最大値を更新しています。

この方法の場合、(当然ですが)データが連続していない場合には期待する結果は得られません。

```
AAA.001
AAA.002
AAA.003
BBB.001
BBB.002
AAA.004  <-- here
BBB.003  <-- here
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！とても参考になりました